# What are some good easily understood books explaining the Postmodernist thinkers (Baudrillard, Derrida, Foucualt, Deleuze)?

Tags: postmodernism, derrida

I am talking bout books like **Hegel: A Biography
by Terry P. Pinkard** which makes his philosophy accessible. I am an engineering student and don't know a lot of theory but I have read Durant, The Second Sex by Simone De Beauvoir, Critique Of Pure reason By Kant which I didn't understand VERY well (untill watching many lectures on it from undergrad classes posted on youtube to get it)
For post-modernism:
I have read Terry Eagleton's Introduction To Literary theory which gave me a good understanding of Structuralism and then Post-Structuralism to show what derrida was trying to do. I have also read Judith Butler's Gender Trouble and understand she is doing to gender what Focault is doing to Sciences and Derrida is doing to words. But I want to understand others like Deleuze, Baudrillard, Rorty etc.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145489/discussion-on-question-by-ash-rivers-what-are-some-good-easily-understood-books); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do worse than Jameson’s *Postmodernism*. I’d also suggest searching for texts focused on single-author overviews — “How to read…” might be a good query to look at to find book titles.